# Reflection c# WPF ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, reflexão, collection

Estou com um problema,  quando se cria um ObservableCollection eu faço assim:

```
ObservableCollection<MinhaClasse> Lista = new ObservableCollection<MinhaClasse>();
```

Até ai tudo bem.
Meu problema é, através do reflection eu leio todos os campos, e se ele for uma Lista como no caso acima, eu preciso criar um novo ObservableCollection

a minha pergunta é: como eu vou fazer isso? como eu vou preencher essa minha class via reflection se eu nao sei qual classe é?

```
 ObservableCollection<????> ListaGeneric = new ObservableCollection<???>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez você devesse detalhar um pouco mais sua questão. Informando, por exemplo, como você está acessando a coleção. Mas, de qualquer forma, segue um exemplo de como criar a instância do ObservableCollection através de um tipo genérico:

```
        var tipo = typeof(string);

        var tipoColecao = typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(tipo);

        var novaLista = Activator.CreateInstance(tipoColecao);
```

Obs.: A variável **novaLista** será um tipo object. Sendo assim, você não poderá chamar novaLista.Add diretamente. Você pode fazer um cast para um IList, caso for chamar o Add "manualmente";

```
        var novaLista = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(tipoColecao);
        novaLista.Add("Meu texto legal");
```